# Set the AutoNumbering on Nikon Digital SLRs?

Tags: nikon, nikon-d3100

I just bought a Nikon D3100 to replace my D50.  I have several thousand pictures numbered DSC_XXXX.jpg from the D50.  The D3100 has started over from Zero.  How do I seed the autonumbers for the files to a higher number to avoid duplicates?  Is this even possible?

Comment: Let it start over and use separate folders. If you already have several thousands, you're halfway to the same problem anyways, which is to work with have the same number. If you want unique filenames than there are plenty of tools which will batch rename and allow larger sequences.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I suggest - insert your SD card with your old images loaded. Let's assume that the last image taken on your old camera was named **DSC_2455.jpg**. Insert that SD Card and only after that turn on the FILE NUMBER SEQUENCE found in the SETUP section of the menu (for d3100) to ON.

It's described in detail here - http://help.nikon.ca/app/answers/detail/a_id/16462/related/1/~/image-file-name%2F-numbering-sequence

Hopefully, the file numbering sequence should then name the first shot on the new camera as "DSC_2456.jpg" and continue on until **DSC_9999.jpg**

Hope this works.

Comment: Actually.  No go on this solution either.  It "remembers" without me.  Any way to clear that memory in a straightforward way?

Comment: Well.. I guess the best thing to do now is to store your older pics in a separate folder.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly sure about the 3100, but as Zoe Bailey mentioned, I configured my D7000 with a different three-letter prefix for the file naming convention.

Specifically, the first two letters are my initials (IP) and the third letter starts with the letter 'A'. So IPA_#####.nef is what I have until the number automatically reaches 10,000.

Then simply change the third letter to 'B' and continue this pattern -- changing the third letter every 10,000 images.

Comment: Indeed it's quite a simple solution. I was frustrated on my D80 to be limited to 9,999 pictures. I thought on newer cameras they would have gone to 99,999 but looks like my D7200 is still limited.

Answer (score 1):

Found this on a website with user guide.  Click Menu and scroll to find menu choice.

> File Number Sequence
>
> The Nikon D3100 will automatically apply a file number to each picture
>   you take, using consecutive numbering for all your photos over a long
>   period of time, spanning many different memory cards, starting over
>   from scratch when you insert a new card, or when you manually reset
>   the numbers. Numbers are applied from 0001 to 9999, at which time the
>   D3100 “rolls over” to 0001 again.
>
> The camera keeps track of the last number used in its internal memory
>   and, if File Number Sequence is turned On, will apply a number that’s
>   one higher, or a number that’s one higher than the largest number in
>   the current folder on the memory card inserted in the camera. You can
>   also start over each time a new folder has been created on the memory
>   card, or reset the current counter back to 0001 at any time. Here’s
>   how it works:
>
> ```
> Off. At this default setting, if you’re using a blank/reformatted memory card, or a new folder is created, the next photo taken will be
> ```
>
> numbered 0001. File number sequences will be reset every time you use
>   or format a card, or a new folder is created (which happens when an
>   existing folder on the card contains 999 shots).
>
> ```
> On. The Nikon D3100 will apply a number one higher than the last picture taken, even if a new folder is created, a new memory card
> ```
>
> inserted, or an existing memory card formatted.
>
> ```
> Reset. The D3100 starts over with 0001, even if a folder containing images exists on the card. In that case, a new folder will
> ```
>
> be created. At this setting, new or reformatted memory cards will
>   always have 0001 as the first file number.

Comment: Please properly quote all off-site content, and also please link the original source of the information so proper credit can be given where due.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can do this on the D3100 - the way I avoided this when i switched cameras was to change the naming convention from DSC to another 3 character combination

on my Nikon - you can do this under the SHOOTING MENU, FILE NAMING

hope you have the same option

Comment: I checked my D3100, I don't think this is an option.

Comment: Oh - sorry, I was hoping it was